# Como procurar dados no MYSQL utilizando Expressões Regulares?

Tags: mysql

É necessário comparar dados do banco de dados MYSQL, mas os dados a comparar não são extremamente iguais. O LIKE do MYSQL não funciona nesse caso pois existem algumas variáveis nessa consulta.

Para exemplificar
Na tabela user, tem o campo "cartas".
As cartas são inseridas da forma abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No modelo acima tem 3 cartas inseridas, mas no sistema são mais de 80 cartas. E o níveis vão de 1 a 20

Preciso então comparar com uma outra tabela, que não terá 80 cartas e sim 3, como abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deverá exibir quais cartas tem nível menor ou igual ao cadastrado. No caso as cartas de id 1201 e 1202 passariam.

Como fazer essa consulta utilizando MYSQL?

Comment: Posso fazer uma pergunta, não seria melhor criar tabelas relacionais separando por "tipos de cartas", "cartas que pessoas possuem" (neste poderia incluir o level), "pessoas"? Quero dizer, assim faria mais sentido o relacionamento do dados, usando chaves estrangeiras, posso formular uma sugestão na resposta que já fiz, só preciso saber se isso lhe atenderia.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia experimentar com `LIKE` mesmo, já que a intenção parece ser buscar apenas pelo numero que vem ante do `LVL`, assim:

```
WHERE (`cartas` LIKE '(1201LVL%;' OR `cartas` LIKE ';1201LVL%') AND ... <outras condições>
```

Seriam apenas 2 *likes*, um para `;` ou seja se o id estiver no meio e outro se estiver no começo com `(`

Agora com regex creio que seria assim (não testei, se falhar me avisa):

```
WHERE `cartas` REGEXP '(\(|;)1201LVL[:digit:]+(\)|;)' AND ... <outras condições>
```

Explicando a regex:

- `(\(|;)` deve começar com `(` ou `;`
- `1201LVL` o 1201 é o valor dinamico, que você deve trocar e o `LVL` parte comum do valor do campo
- `[:digit:]+` busca qualquer numero que vier depois de LVL, como LVL1, LVL2, LVL3, etc
- `(\)|;)` deve terminar com `)` ou `;` (apesar que no final isso é meio redundante já que a primeira as partes anteriores da regex já resolveriam)